# Determine figure by binnary two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, artificial-intelligence

i use c++
i've 2d array consisted with 0,1. The 1 draw a figure of circle/square/triangle(only this 3, and only 1 figure possible). The figure does not touch the borders. It does not exceed the bounds. Size of the biggest side or the radius of the figure is not less than 30px. The least angle of the triangle is not less than 10 degrees.
I tried to calculate frequencies of appearing black cells for every row and column. It should allow to recognize the figure i think.

If anyone can give any idea/code of solution, it will be very nice.

Comment: if you have (1 1 \n 1 1), would it be considered square or circle?

Comment: well, the issue is generally for >30px figures

Comment: are the shapes always centered and/or always the same size?

Comment: This sounds a bit like a homework task, so we're reluctant to spoil all the fun of finding your own solution by giving too many hints, but I guess the trick is to detect straight lines (or their absence)

Comment: no, not always centered. The main problem is to differ centered square from circle

Comment: Is the square axis aligned ?

Comment: http://rghost.ru/51520689/image.png  actually both are possible

Answer (score 0):

Look for vertices, or corners.  A corner pixel is surrounded by fewer pixels than an edge pixel.  A square will have 4 corners, a triangle fewer, and a circle may have either many or none, depending on how you detect the corners.  Also, your minimum size and minimum angle guarantee that no two corners will be close together.  Fun problem.